# Change the baseline of \cite temporarily?

Tags: citing

I'm using the `cite` package with the `superscript` argument (i.e. ref<sup>1</sup>). However, in some points in the document I'd like to temporarily switch the cite style to on-line (i.e. ref [1]).

Is this possible?

Edit: If I have this document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[superscript,nospace,nobreak]{cite} %Citations in superscript

\begin{document}
%Citation in superscript
See reference \cite{exampleItem} 
%Citation on same line?
See reference on-same-line \cite{exampleItem}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
 \bibitem{exampleItem}
  John Doe,
  A Book
  Publisher
  Edition,
  1994.
 \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Right now both lines will output See reference<sup>1</sup>, whereas I would like to be able to change the citation style to See reference [1] for the second line. Then revert to the superscript style for the rest of the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your code: the correct answer will depend on what packages (if any) you are loading.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question as advised, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is slightly hacky, it works. In case you want a cleaner solution, have a look at package `natbib`: http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[superscript,nospace,nobreak]{cite} %Citations in superscript

% Redefine the string before the optional note to be blank
\renewcommand\citemid{}

\begin{document}
%Citation in superscript
See reference \cite{exampleItem} 

%Citation on same line
See reference on-same-line \cite[]{exampleItem}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
 \bibitem{exampleItem}
  John Doe,
  A Book
  Publisher
  Edition,
  1994.
 \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]